# php foreach print <br> tag if different date

Tags: php, loops

I hope I can be clear enough.
I'm retrieving dates from database (day only). I have a loop and I want to print something like that:

```
1 april
1 april

2 april

3 april
3 april
3 april
```

etc...

So : same days = no `<br>` tag, different days print a `<br>`.

My actual code:

```
$prec;
                      foreach ($list as $rs) {
                          $day = date("d", strtotime($rs['date']))." ";
                          if ($day === $prec) {
                              $space = "";
                          } else {
                              $space ="<br>";
                          }
                          $prec = $day;
                          echo $day;
                          echo date("F", strtotime($rs['date'])).", ";
                          echo $space;
                          }
```

But this output is wrong:

```
23 March
25 March

27 March

27 March
27 March
27 March
27 March
28 March

28 March
28 March
02 April

03 April

04 April
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the placement of where you output the line break - if you output the line break before the date rather than after, the output will be as intended.

```
echo $space;
echo $day;
echo date("F", strtotime($rs['date'])).", ";
```

That is because your comparison is based on how the current value compares to the previous one, so the generated result needs to be placed between these two days to follow the same logic

Keep in mind that your code will still return wrong output if you happen to have the same day in a separate month next to each other, because you only compare by day (if you compare by the full date, it will work better)

Comment: thank you , that worked. About comparison I know, I will probably adjust it later if needed. :)

Answer (score 0):

you have to echo $space before echo $day

```
//same days = no <br> tag, different days print a <br>

    $list = [1, 3, 3, 3,4 ];
    $prec ='';
    foreach ($list as $day) {
      if ($day === $prec) {
          $space = ",";
      } else {
          $space ="<br>";
      }
      echo $space;
      echo $day;
      $prec = $day;
    }
```

Result :

```
<br>1<br>3,3,3<br>4
```